# cd to parent directory without knowing absolute path to it

Tags: bash, cd

I need to get back to a parent directory inside of a bash script. I know that the directory will be in my current path, but not how far up it is as the script could have put me anywhere from 2 to 5 levels deep. The script is part of a cloned git repo so I can't start from the user's root since I won't know where they've cloned it to or how many levels down it will be.

Let's say my file structure looks like this:

```
User's dir structure
  repo
    foo
      bar
       baz
        a
       fizz
        b
        bang
          c
```

I need to get back to `foo`, but I don't know offhand if I'm in `a`, `b`, or `c`, or even `bar`.

My current thought is to pwd and cut it so I have just `*/foo/` then cd to that, but is that really the most efficient way?

Comment: Set an environment variable that points to `foo` at the start of your script?

Comment: Is `foo` always at the same place? If so you could just do `foo="/home/user/foo" at the beggining and then cd back into the folder

Comment: @Rudedog Why an environment variable rather than a normal shell variable?

Comment: @Sami nope, like I said it's entirely up to the user where they clone into - the repo could be at /home/user/repo/foo or /home/user/x/y/z/repo/foo - no way to tell

Comment: A shell variable would likely be fine as well although an environment variable would ensure that it is passed to other scripts that might be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a variable to the original directory.

```
origdir=$(pwd)
# code that jumps around...
cd "$origdir"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the directory stack.

```
pushd -n "$PWD"  # Store the current working directory on the stack
...
popd  # Return to the directory on top of the stack
```

This is especially useful if you don't need to do a lot of directory changes between the `pushd` and the `popd`, as you can simply write

```
pushd some/directory/path  # Puts current working dir on the stack, then cd's to the argument
...
popd
```

(Even if there are changes, you can still use `pushd`. `pushd foo` is equivalent to `pushd -n "$PWD"; cd foo`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the root of your repository like this:

```
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

So, to get from anywhere inside the repo to the `foo` directory in its root:

```
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/foo"
```

---

[`git-rev-parse` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-toplevel)